# How can I make this "percentage-only" Regex works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I'm trying to achieve a scenario where I can limit my string to tree digits one dot and  two digits being the dot and the last two digits optional.

e.g.:

- 100.00
- 1
- 10.56
- 31.5

I could achieve a regex that allow me to avoid other besides dot and comma, and I remove the extra dots.

```
function isPercentage(input){
    var regex = /[^0-9\.]/g;

    var value = input.replace(regex, '');
    var index = value.indexOf( '.' );
    if ( index > -1 ) {
        value = value.substr( 0, index + 1 ) +
        value.slice( index ).replace( /\./g, '' );
    }
    return value;
}
```

I tried the following regex, based on knowledge of regex (if it can be considered any...)

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{3}\.{1}[0-9]{2}$/g;
```

But now it doesn't show any error nor it work at all.

---

I'm using this function in `jQuery(document).on('focusout',`, `jQuery(document).on('paste',` and `jQuery(document).on('keyup',` (I separated them to make things easy to ready)

Snippet

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).on('focusout','.decimal_only', function(){
    jQuery(this).val(isPercentage(jQuery(this).val()));
  });
  
  jQuery(document).on('paste','.decimal_only', function(){
    var element = jQuery(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
      var v = element.val();
      element.val(isPercentage(v));
    }, 100);
  });
  
  jQuery(document).on('keyup','.decimal_only', function(){
    var kc = event.keyCode;
  var cmdKeys = [9,13,16,17,18,19,20,27,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,91,92,93,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,144,145];
  if(jQuery.inArray(kc,cmdKeys) == -1) {
   jQuery(this).val(isPercentage(jQuery(this).val()));
  }
 });
});

function isPercentage(input){
  var regex = /[^0-9\.]/g;

  var value = input.replace(regex, '');
  var index = value.indexOf( '.' );
  if ( index > -1 ) {
    value = value.substr( 0, index + 1 ) +
      value.slice( index ).replace( /\./g, '' );
  }
  return value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="decimal_only" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/m;
```

With `\d{1, 3}` you ask for 1 to 3 digits. With `\.\d{1,2}` you ask for a dot followed by 1 to 2 digits. Putting the previous expression inside `(...)?` you make it optional.

Comment: you don't need to have a g modifier. Add m modifier is the input contain multiple lines.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. As you can see in the question, I'm using it on a replace (not sure if that matters). It doesn't show errors nor it work (it allows alpha characters for example) this is how I add it `var regex = /^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$/m;` (replacing the regex position in my function)

Comment: changing to `var regex = /[^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?]$/m;` it works like `/[^0-9\.]/g` allowing **3333.3** and **3.333** for example.

Comment: @MichelAyres can you describe what `isPercentage` tries to do? and give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I'll create a fiddle. isPercentage, right now receive the content of an input text. and return the "correct" value back to the input (vide `replace`)

Comment: Ok tell me an incorrect value and the corrected one

Comment: I added an snippet. **incorrect** => 1000 **incorrect** => 1000.00 **incorrect** => 100.000 **correct** => 100 **correct** => 100.00 **correct** => 100.1

Comment: This Works: \d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?

Comment: @MikeG I couldn't make this works. Could you create a working fiddle, so I can adapt to my code?